# How to store a tag visited state after calling preventDefault in click event?

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have couple of a tags in my page. Clicking each result in opening a popup dialog showing detail about blog post (preventing a tag default behavior e.g.: making it visited). So what I want to do is after showing popup dialog set visited state of a tag manually.

My code look something like this:

```
$("a.news-part").click(function(e){
    //do popup
    e.preventDefault();
    //here I want to store a tag visited state.
});
```

Any help is very appreciated.

Comment: what is the behavior of the visited state? which default behavior are you trying to prevent?

Comment: The built in `:visited` state can't be set manually, it's something the browser keeps track of, and that's why links that you've visisted gets that state, even if they where visisted without following the actual link. You can set a sort of visited state with a class, or you could use a hidden iframe to load the link to make it visited, or even use the HTML5 history API to fake it, if older browsers are'nt a problem.

Comment: 1 : i want to apply some style to visited a tags. 2: navigating to other page.

Comment: To style a visited link, all you have to do is `a:visited {color:red}`, but that won't work if the default action is prevented, as the user will never visit that page, and the `:visited` state will not be set! You can set a class like in the answer below, but that kind of "state" will not keep on page reload.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this...

```
$("a.news-part").click(function(e){
        //do popup
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).addClass('visited')
   });
```

Then, in your CSS, you'd just need to do...`a:visited, a.visited` or something along those lines per your actual CSS.

Comment: are you sure this will store a tag as visited in browser history?

Comment: no it won't but you just need the style to look like it don't you??

Comment: but what after navigating away from the page? and get back to that page later?

Comment: well I don't see any harm of the anchor not being in a visited state when the user comes to the page again at a later time. But if you really want it to store in browser history... then you will have to fake a click with hidden iframe or something similar

Comment: thanks @Huangism for your response.i will check for more complete solution , and will use your's in case of failure.

Answer (score 0):

Other than the other proposed solution, you could use `history.pushState` on modern browsers. However, I have not tested yet whether that will actually mark the link as visited.

A browser assings the `:visited` pseudo class once the link is in its history. You could support older browsers if you replaced your links in runtime with *hash history hack* compliant URLs. Do a little bit of googling, there are a lot of StackOverflow questions on that already, in case you don't know what I'm talking about.

Good luck!